# How to add app to "Open With" default programs list when it Installed on Windows?

Tags: java, swing, file-association

I have developed small editor using Java and installed that into my Windows 10 Machine. But, it was not added to the "Open With" Default programs list when file is selected. I have shown an example of requirement in image. How to solve my issue?

[image]

Comment: Your installer must add a Windows registry key-values to handle all the file types your app can open. Good luck!

Comment: @cricket_007 No need for luck here. See the duplicate.